# iOS Spinning Wheel HTML5

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a webapp that will be used on iOS devices as well as Desktops (without touch).
We are using a bootstrap to make the site as responsive as possible.

We want to incoperate the spinning wheel known in iOS.
We will style it differently but not the functionality.

[image: Spinning Wheel]

After some searching I came across this site:
[http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel](http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch)

However this script only seems to work on touch capable devices. Would it be possible to edit the script so it will work on desktops too?

I found this in the script can I add a mouseClickHandler here?

```
handleEvent: function (e) {
        console.log(e.type);
        if (e.type == 'touchstart') {
            this.lockScreen(e);
            if (e.currentTarget.id == 'sw-cancel' || e.currentTarget.id == 'sw-done') {
                this.tapDown(e);
            } else if (e.currentTarget.id == 'sw-frame') {
                this.scrollStart(e);
            }
        } else if (e.type == 'touchmove') {
            this.lockScreen(e);

            if (e.currentTarget.id == 'sw-cancel' || e.currentTarget.id == 'sw-done') {
                this.tapCancel(e);
            } else if (e.currentTarget.id == 'sw-frame') {
                this.scrollMove(e);
            }
        } else if (e.type == 'touchend') {
            if (e.currentTarget.id == 'sw-cancel' || e.currentTarget.id == 'sw-done') {
                this.tapUp(e);
            } else if (e.currentTarget.id == 'sw-frame') {
                this.scrollEnd(e);
            }
        } else if (e.type == 'webkitTransitionEnd') {
            if (e.target.id == 'sw-wrapper') {
                this.destroy();
            } else {
                this.backWithinBoundaries(e);
            }
        } else if (e.type == 'orientationchange') {
            this.onOrientationChange(e);
        } else if (e.type == 'scroll') {
            this.onScroll(e);
        }
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using `drag` events, but they aren't supported well. Check out [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop) and [this one](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html) with more explanation on the events. You could also try using jQuery with for instance [this plugin](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/). Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

for everybody looking for that cool scroll snapping effect in 2023 - there is a scroll-snap-* CSS properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type. For examples and tailwinds css users - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/scroll-snap-type